# Rstudio and shiny server proxy setting

Tags: nginx, proxy, rstudio, shiny-server

i have installed RStudio Server v0.98.507 and Shiny Server v1.1.0.10000 on my ubuntu14

my rstudio proxy setting on **nginx default**

```
location /rstudio/ {
     rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
     proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
}
```

that' my shiny server setting at **/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf**

```
    # Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
        run_as shiny;

    # Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
        server {
      # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
      listen 3838;

          # Define the location available at the base URL
      location / {


        # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
        # tree at '/srv/shiny-server'
        site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

        # Define where we should put the log files for this location
        log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

        # Should we list the contents of a (non-Shiny-App) directory when the user 
        # visits the corresponding URL?
        directory_index on;
      }
    }
```

i can run both rstudio and shiny-server, however, when i call a shiny example such as

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

when RStudio complier prompt

```
Listening on http://'127.0.0.1':7146
```

the url return a invalid response and here the console on my chrome shown

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com/rstudio/p/7146/websocket/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 mydomaion.com/rstudio/p/7146/shared/shiny.js:507
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

However, when i remove the proxy bypass of the RStudio in **nginx default** to

```
 #location /rstudio/ {
 #        rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
 #       proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
 #      proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
 # }
```

it can run the shiny application from RStudio.

My question is how could i config the RStudio and Shiny server so i could remove :8787 to run the rstudio and :3838 to run the shiny server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> RStudio complier prompt
>
> `Listening on http://'127.0.0.1':7146`

Doesn't this mean that you should be passing the proxied request to `7146` rather than `8787`?

The 404 error message indicates that the path isn't found.

To answer the question more directly, look here: http://table1.org/setting-up-an-ubuntu-server-with-nginx-up-to-run-shiny-applications.

That page gives the nginx siteconf file to read:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name shinyapp.domain.name;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://server-ip-address:3838/shinyapp/;
            proxy_redirect http://server-ip-address:3838/ $scheme:$host/;
    }
}
```

So, you should be able to run your shiny server without having to proxy it through RStudio. Since you want to run it in a sub directory, you might be able to use this code:

```
location /rstudio/ {
     rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
     proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try changing out `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` or the actual ip address.

Comment: This was really helpful but the link doesn't work anymore